# SNMP error reporting to stdout

Tags: bash, snmp, stderr

Why does net-snmp after "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" errors exit with `0` and print the error message to `STDOUT` while other errors are printed to `STDERR` and have an exit status `1`? Compare:

```
$ /usr/bin/snmpget -Oqv -v2c -cpublic localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 2> /dev/null
No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
$ echo $?
0
```

A erroneous community string or IP-Address, however, is handled differently (e.g. "publi" instead of "public"):

```
$ /usr/bin/snmpget -Oqv -v2c -cpubli localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 2>&1 > /dev/null
Timeout: No Response from localhost.
$ echo $?
1
```

This is really irritating as I'm trying to write a function that does some sanity checks to make sure that certain MIBs/OIDs are indeed available on the agent to be queried. I'd like to be able to do something like this (in a bash script):

```
snmp_sanity_checks() {
  ...
  if ! err=$($snmpcmd); then
    echo "ERROR: $err"
    exit $UNKNOWN
  fi
  ...
}
```

Does anybody know the reason for this and how I can "fix" it?

Thanks

Comment: As it turns out, "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" is not considered to be an error per se but an exception (for all versions > 1). This also means that there's no simple check for whether a variable holds valid data or not, because `err` in the above example will not be empty if an exception occurs. Workaround: use snmp version 1

Answer (score 1):

As another workaround, you can do this:

```
snmp_sanity_checks() {
  ...
  if ! err=$($snmpcmd); then
    echo "ERROR: $err"
    exit $UNKNOWN
  elif [[ $err == 'No Such Object'* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $err"
    exit $UNKNOWN
  fi
  ...
}
```

Or if you want to handle both situations the same way then this works too:

```
snmp_sanity_checks() {
  ...
  if ! err=$($snmpcmd) || [[ $err == 'No Such Object'* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $err"
    exit $UNKNOWN
  fi
  ...
}
```